# Use a container div only on certain pages in rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails

In my application view I have

```
  <div class="push-in">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="flash_messages">
        <%= flash_messages %>
      </div>
        <%= yield %>
     </div>
   </div>
```

But I want to make it so that if a specific page is called then it would remove the container div. What is the best syntax to use. I have about 12 pages that I need to remove the container div for only in the entire app.

I currently have this...

```
<% if current_page?(welcome_index_path) || current_page?(tenants_path)|| current_page?(root_url) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial1_path) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial2_path) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial3_path) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial4_path) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial5_path) || current_page?(welcome_testimonial6_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial1_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial2_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial3_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial4_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial5_path) || current_page?(welcome_man_testimonial6_path)%>
          <div class="push-in">
            <div class="container">
              <div id="flash_messages">
                <%= flash_messages %>
              </div>
            </div>
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
    <% else %>
        <div class="push-in">
          <div class="container">
              <div id="flash_messages">
                <%= flash_messages %>
              </div>
            <%= yield %>
          </div>
        </div>
    <% end %>
```

But this seems totally stinky to me,  to check each page upon a page rendering. How can I clean this up?

Comment: It would probably be best if you could either always use the container div or never use it. What types of problems do you wish to solve by removing that element? Styling issues?

Comment: Yes, the pages I dont want to use the container div go full screen while the rest of this site does not

Answer (score 0):

Create a method inside helper something like this

```
def check_page(page_url)
  case page_url
  when welcome_index_path || tenants_path
    true
  else
    false
  end
end
```

You are hiding and showing only one div

```
 <div class="push-in">
    <div class="container">
      <div id="flash_messages">
        <%= flash_messages %>
      </div>
    </div>
    <%= yield %>
  </div>
<% unless check_page(current_url) %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**Note** Generate current page URL dynamically and define those URL inside the helper method and match for this method

If you are working with any cms kind of thing then it will be good to add a flag to check it.

Comment: current_page is throwing a ````undefined local variable or method `current_page'```` error on the html page

Comment: @SupremeA ok let me check it check the current url

Comment: Not sure I understand. Check the current page first then send it to the helper method? Why would I need the helper method then. Can you update the answer?

Comment: @SupremeA pass the current page URL which you are checking in your if condition in this case you need not check current_page, and how URL is coming define inside the helper method